# Firebase functions -get fcm token from user id

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to send push notification to specific user,
but i dont know his fcm token.

Is it possible to get the fcm token of user from his user id?

Comment: this should assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67150023/4628115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user may be using multiple devices.  You should expect this to be the case.  You'll need to store each device token for all devices that a particular user may be using in order to notify them.  Typically, Firebase apps will use Realtime Database to record the token at the time of login.

Comment: According to my understanding firebase send the APNs tokens off to FCM and Get back the FCM device token, does it mean that firebase is responsible for saving the device toke?.
what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Your app is responsible for saving the token somewhere if it's going to be used somewhere later.  If you need to associate that with an authenticated user, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: I think you have to use something called token registery which would map username/userID to their token. You need to access this token registery inside you app server.

Comment: the answer doesn't actually answer the question. OP asked is it (and by extension) how is it possible to do so.

Comment: @CybeX The answer states that Realtime Database is one way to store the token.  But you can use *any* persistent storage that you want that allows you to store data for a string key (the user's UID).

Comment: @DougStevenson see the comment I left on the question - this, I believe, is a possible correct answer to the question OP asked (i.e. I need FCM token, what code do I use to get it). Feel free to update your answer with some implementable solution.