# How can I read a device Token in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've managed to push notifications successfully whenever the real-time database changes through FCM, and ultimately through the Firebase Cloud Functions

But I do so by setting a

`const registrationToken = "........"`

and then adding it when I return the notification

`return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options);`

My question is, how can I read my device's token instead of hard-coding it in, since if I were to share this application I would assume the token for each device would be different.

Answer (score 1):

The typical process is to:

1. Have the client store their device token in the database upon startup, for example associated with the UID of the user or other properties that you use to target your messages.
2. Have the Cloud Function then read from the "token registry" to target and send the messages.

If you have a Cloud Function that your users call directly to send/receive/register for messages, consider implementing that as a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) in which case the FCM token is available automatically in your Cloud Function code as `context.instanceIdToken`.

Comment: I think the context.instanceIdToken is exactly what I needed, but considering I have an `exports.pushNotification` function with an `.onWrite` on a reference to the database, I used this context. Unfortunately when I print it out it says "undefined".

Comment: This value is only available for **callable** Cloud Functions. For other Cloud Functions types you'll have to pass the value in yourself, for example as part of the data you write to the database.

Comment: `exports.UserToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { const TokenVal = context.instanceIdToken; console.log("Token Value ", context.instanceIdToken); return{ TokenVal }});` This is how I implemented it, but for the life of me can't figure out how to call it. I'm pushing notifications on an iOS.

Comment: The documentation shows how to call such a Cloud Function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function If you're having a hard time making that work, I recommend starting a new question for specifically that. My answer is only meant to show you the options of getting the FCM token from the client into your Cloud Functions code.